# Implement Queue using Linked List in C

Tags: c, linked-list, queue, output

This code is used to implement queues and some operations in C by using a linked list. I get unexpected output, especially the line "After removing front item: ", but I don't know why.

Here is my code:

```
// C program to implement linked list queue
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Define a queue using linked list
typedef struct _Node {
    int data;
    struct _Node *next;
}Node;

typedef struct _Queue {
    Node *pFront, *pBack;
    int size;
}Queue;

// Initialize queue
Queue *init (void) {
    Queue *q = malloc(sizeof(*q));
    if (q) {
    q->size = 0;
    q->pFront = q->pBack = NULL;
    }
    return q;
}

// Check if queue is empty
int isEmpty (Queue q) {
    return (q.pFront == NULL);
}

// Length of train
int Length(Queue *q) {
    return q->size;
}

// Add new item
void enqueue (Queue *q, int val)
{
    Node *p = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    p->data = val;
    p->next = NULL;

    // If queue is empty
    if (q->pFront == NULL)
        q->pFront = q->pBack = p;

    // If queue has at least 1 element
    else {
        p->next = q->pBack;
        q->pBack = p;
    }
    q->size++;
}

// Remove item
int dequeue (Queue *q)
{
    if (isEmpty(*q))
        return 0;
    else {
        if (q->size == 1) {
            q->pFront = q->pBack = NULL;
            q->size--;
        }
        else {
            Node *p = q->pBack;
            while (p->next != q->pFront)
                p = p->next;
            q->pFront = p;
            q->pFront->next = NULL;
            q->size--;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

// Display queue
void display(Queue *q) {
    Node *p = q->pBack;
    while (p != NULL) {
        printf("%d\t", p->data);
        p = p->next;
    }
}

// Free all memory used by the stack
void freeMemory(Queue *q) {
    Node* p = q->pFront;
    Node* next;

    while (p != NULL) {
        next = p->next;
        free(p);
        p = next;
    }

    q->pFront = NULL;
    q->size = 0;
}

int main()
{
    Queue *q;
    q = init();
    if (q)
    {
    enqueue(q, 10);
    enqueue(q, 20);
    enqueue(q, 30);
    printf("Queue:\n");
    display(q);

    printf("\nAfter removing front item: %d", dequeue(q));
    display(q);

    printf("\nLength of the queue after all modification: %d", Length(q));

    freeMemory(q);
    return 0;
    }
}
```

Unexpected output:
**
Queue:
10      20      30
After removing front item: 110    20
Length of the queue after all modification: 2
**

Comment: Too complicated. I would use two separate pointers - the `head` and the `tail`.


You add only to the `head` ant take from the `tail`. No traversing needed.

Comment: I agree, @0___________, but it is worth mentioning that avoiding list traversals that way requires a doubly-linked list, whereas the OP is presently using a singly-linked one.

Comment: Your `freeMemory()` function needs to start at the back instead of at the front, and when done it needs to set the queue's back pointer null, too.

Comment: Is the code all your own work?  It's enough stylistically inconsistent to make me wonder.

Comment: @JohnBollinger no, it does not require.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I change the freeMemory() but it does not work. The function enqueue and dequeue come from my teacher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output is misleading you because you do not consistently print a newlines at the end.  In particular, here:

> ```
>     printf("\nAfter removing front item: %d", dequeue(q));
>     display(q);
> ```

... the return value of `dequeue()` (always 1 or 0) is printed and then the values of the remaining queue items are printed without any leading space.  Your

> 110 20

could thus be broken down as 1 (return value of `dequeue()`), 10 (queue item), 20 (queue item).

That would be wrong, because the first item dequeued should be the first one enqueued (10).  **That's not what your program prints for me, however**.  When I run your program, I get

```
After removing front item: 130  20
Length of the queue after all modification: 2
```

That shows the correct item having been removed.  However, my naive expectation would be that that the queue would be printed in the order that the elements will be dequeued, which is the reverse of the order your program emits.

At minimum, add those missing newlines to your program's output.  Do also verify the wanted output order for `display()`, and fix it if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the previous answer...

When enqueing a `Node` item to the queue, you are adding to the back of the queue, which is correct as per the FIFO principle.

However when dequeing a `Node` from the queue, the code cannot remove the node currently at the front of the queue directly. With the direction in which the `next` pointers are pointing, the code in `dequeue()` needs to start from the back of the queue and traverse the entire linked list of nodes to reach the front of the queue. It would be a better implementation if the node at the front of the queue is directly accessed via `pFront` and removed in O(1) time, but in the present code submitted by the OP `pFront` can't be set to point to the next node in the FIFO list because the node being currently removed from the front of the FIFO list does not have a pointer to it's preceding node (`pFront->next` for the node in front is always NULL).

Also due to the direction each node's `next` pointers are pointing, the function `display()` can only print from the back of the queue to the front, and not from the front of the queue to the back.

You should also free the memory for each individual node item at the time the individual node is being dequeued inside the function `dequeue()`, otherwise you have memory leaks for nodes already dequeued as you are only freeing the remaining nodes left in the queue at the very end of the program when `freeMemory()` is called.